# Sending array of objects trough x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: arrays, http, react-native

I want to send an array of objects trough a fetch call in react native in x-www-form-urlencoded format

```
global.modifiedOffline.forEach((elem)=>{
   data["array[]"] = elem;
});
alert(data);
const formBody = Object.keys(data).map(key => encodeURIComponent(key) + 
'=' + encodeURIComponent(data[key])).join('&');
```

This is what i've been trying to do but in the back end server i get a list of:
['[object Object]' ... ] which i cannot parse or use.

Comment: you have to at least use `JSON.stringify(data[key])`

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are encoding objects. When you try to do that, encodeURIComponent tries to get a string representation of the object you supply it and `[Object object]` is the string representation in JS.

In order to be able to encode it, first you need to get it into a proper string format such as JSON as suggested by @Val. However, this part depends on the server side implementation you have. `encodeURIComponent` will only transform your string into URI component by replacing characters such as space with their escape counterparts (for example, %20).